# java print in textarea text file in reverse order

Tags: java

I'm using this code, it runs well but i need to add "`\n`" to each line

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    filename = "Reverse.txt";
    file = new File(filename);
    try (final Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename))) {
        lines.collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new))
        .descendingIterator()
        .forEachRemaining(jTextArea1::append); // <<<<<<< need "\n"
    }   
    catch (IOException ex) {                
        Logger.getLogger(TextAreaReverseReadFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }                
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try to change

```
.forEachRemaining(jTextArea1::append);
```

to:

```
.forEachRemaining(singleLine -> jTextArea1.append(singleLine  + "\n"));
```

Comment: I think it would be more stream-esque if you add \n to the text with a separate .map call

Comment: I don't understand what that has to do with my comment

Comment: thanks Pijotrek, your code solved my problem, why I can not vote up ?

Answer (score 1):

You can transform each line at source, meaning adding a map instruction just before the collect one:

```
lines.map(element -> element + '\n').collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new)).descendingIterator()
                .forEachRemaining(testBuilder::append);
```

Comment: thanks Bsquare, at the beginning I did not understand your solution, but it works well